# PhpStorm change rest client "headers" and "request parameters" areas are empty

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I am using phpstorm built-in rest client to test my restful api service. But there is a problem, like the following pictures:

1. The areas are empty:

[image]

2. I am ready to add a name request paremeter:

[image]

3. I added the parameter, but the area is blank.[image]
4. But If I move the mouse to the green row, it shows the parameter:

[image]

So I think it might be caused by background color, someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exact version are you using? Try to update to latest (2017.1.4) and check it there.
Also please disable all custom plugins (File | Settings | Plugins > Show: Custom).
You can also check if that would work for you in [EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).